# How to tell if a hard drive with Windows was used in AHCI or RAID mode?

Tags: windows, bios, external-hard-drive, raid, ahci

I have a computer with a corrupted windows installation that will not boot into the OS. I am trying to fix the operating system, but I am not sure at this point if the drive was using RAID or AHCI. How can I tell which one it was using? Thanks!

Comment: Why does it matter if it was RAID or AHCI?

Comment: @jo99blackops: 
Not mentioning the version of your operating system might cause wrong answers.

Answer (score 0):

## Look it up in your BIOS

You could look this information up in your BIOS. There is a switch that should let you choose between AHCI or RAID. This setting determines the mode of your hardware (AHCI or RAID) and requires the installation of a different driver for each mode.

If you are not booting from a disk that is connected to the mainboard hardware but an extension card like PCI(e) you would pause the boot process when the BIOS message from that card appears. I it might state something like
"2009 Silicon Image RAID bios". The bios of extension cards sometimes has no switch but can be flashed with either an AHCI bios or a RAID bios.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what r2d3 said, there is no way to "check" the drive(without windows), you can set it in bios and hope for the best in regards to boot.
If drive is AHCI formatted and you place it as RAID(in bios), you should get a BSOD with error "Inaccessible boot device" or similar. What kind of BSOD you get, might point out to disk mode.
Keep in mind that older systems had IDE as an option also.

If you have other boot disk(or any live USB), and just plugin this 2nd drive, you shouldn't have any issues in reading the data.